# Adding a row to a data frame with a concrete numeric name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

To add a row to a data frame I can do like in the next example:

```
> result <- rbind(baskets.df, c(7, 4))
> result
  Granny Geraldine
1st   12     5
2nd   4     4
3rd   5     2
4th   6     4
5th   9    12
6th   3     9
7    7     4
```

If further, I want to put the new row a (numeric) name, let's 2005, I would do

```
> result <- rbind(baskets.df, "2005" = c(7, 4))
> result
  Granny Geraldine
1st   12     5
2nd   4     4
3rd   5     2
4th   6     4
5th   9    12
6th   3     9
2005    7     4
```

But if I have 2005 saved in a variable,

```
> syear <- 2005
```

and I want the new name (`2005` in the present case) to depend on the number assigned to `syear`, how can I do?

If I make what It seems to me the most natural option

```
> result <- rbind(baskets.df, as.character(syear) = c(7, 4))
```

I get an error `Error: unexpected '=' in "rbind(baskets.df, as.character(syear) ="`.

If I try

```
> result <- rbind(baskets.df, syear = c(7, 4))
```

the resulting name is not `2005`, but `syear`.

What do you suggest to me?

Thanks!

Comment: In general adding one row at a time to a data.frame is not the most efficient operation. Are you sure you need to do this? What is your ultimate goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an assignment

```
result[as.character(syear),] <- c(7, 4)
```

#### data

```
result <- structure(list(Granny = c(12L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 7L), Geraldine = c(5L, 
 4L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1st", 
 "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7"))
```